# jupyter-notebookにおけるCheckpoint autosave ローカルに保存の違いについてわかりません．

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

`Julia`で`jupyter-notebook`を使用しています．(`IJulia: v1.14.1`)
`jupyter-notebook`上で`command-s`を打てばローカル(`Users/username/hoge_note.ipynb`)に保存されますが，自動保存させたいと思っています．
しかし，ブラウザ上で`autosaved`と表示されているのに，ローカルでは保存されず，困っています．`autosaved`と`command-s`で保存した時の挙動は本質的に違うものなのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします．

Comment: 正しいという確信が持てない（&& ソースが見つからない）のでコメントで失礼します。autosaveは不意のクラッシュに備えてクッキーなどブラウザ側に一時的に最新版を自動保存する機能で、一方`command-s`などの保存はファイルの更新を行いつつ、後からリバート出来るようにバージョンを更新するようです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．ついでにお聞きしたいのですが，`Python`でいう`%Autosave 600`や`Julia`でいう`display("text/javascript", "Jupyter.notebook.set_autosave_interval(600000)")`というコマンドで`autosave`の間隔を変えることはできるのですが，`command-s`を自動的に行って欲しい場合はどうすれば良いのでしょうか．

Comment: 今回の質問と別の内容になりますので、新しく質問を立ててください。

Comment: わかりました．質問を立てたので，もしよろしければコメント等お願いします．